# An application of Euler Characteristic to Tetrahedron Packing

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

The following is an application of Euler's equation to tetrahedron packing of any convex polyhedron. I related it to Euler formula; consequently, a third equation is obtained which is independent of both the number of vertices and Euler characteristic.

**Variables**

$V$ is the number of vertices;
$E$ is the number of edges;
$F$ is the number of faces;
$T$ is the number of tetrahedrons;
$N'$ is the number of triangulated planes shared between tetrahedrons that fill a given polyhedron

**Equations**

*Euler Equation*
$V-E+F=2$

*A reformulation of Euler's formula, as Sunghyuk Park proved in the comments below, with application to tetrahedron packing*
$V-2T+N'=2$

*How it relates to Eruler's equation*
$V-E+F=V-2T+N';\\
-E+F=-2T+N'$

Node: I modified the body in response to your valued feedback.
My question originally was 'how to best share such things?'. I should have done this on mathoverflow.

Comment: This site is not really for original research or opinions on it, unless there is a very specific question. You might want to ask in math.Overflow if your conjecture is a well known consequence of one of the generalizations that already exist . Asking how to communicate it is getting a bit ahead of yourself

Comment: @rschwieb I don't know what to do. These have been sitting in my notebook for many years. I figured that sharing them here is better than keeping them buried with me.

Comment: Sure, by all means share, but not really here. Consider deleting this question from here and reposting at http://mathoverflow.net/ (but avoid leaving both questions up at the same time.)

Comment: @MoustaphaItani, never name an equation after yourself! When you encounter a named equation like "Euler's formula," it was not named by Euler, but by other mathematicians. Naming it after yourself is a sure way to have people treat your claims dismissively.

Comment: I also didnt know that. I will delete this and then share a more elaborate description. Thank you.

Comment: Do not deface your post by removing its body or significantly altering it. That makes the answers incomprehensible. I rolled the question back to match the version that Sunghyuk Park answered. He helped you, so give him the courtesy of leaving your question as it was answered.

Comment: I just felt awkward :(

Comment: I see. Make minor edits to reduce the awkwardness, and we can delete comments that became obsolete. No real harm was done:-) This is just something users here take very seriously. Now you know.

Answer (score 6):

There are linear relations: $E=6T-3N$, $F=4T-2N$. First one because before gluing of tetrahedra, we have 6T edges in total, but for each gluing, 3 are reduced. The second one is because before gluing we have 4T faces in total, which is reduced by 1 for each gluing.

Therefore, $2=V-E+F=V-(6T-3N)+(4T-2N)=V-2T+N$, proving your claim. (Unfortunately, your equation turns out to be nothing but a reformulation of Euler's formula.)

Comment: Shouldn't this be noted somewhere? I mean, it shows that Euler's formula has implications on Tetrahedron packing.

Comment: You mean "triangulation", not "packing of tetrahedra"? I don't feel like it says anything more than Euler's formula as Euler's formula itself relates the topology of a polyhedra to its triangulation.

Comment: I am saying packing of tetrahedra. Consider trying it. Draw any polyhedron. Triangulate the planes inside the polyhedron. Break the polyhedron into tetrahedra. The equation will apply in relating T, V and N'.

Comment: @MoustaphaItani That is what mathematicians call "triangulation".

Comment: The gluing that you talked about is taking place on the inside. It is like describing the internal structure of a polyhedron. I will expand the above to include the equations I found for determining other things. I will share that on mathoverflow.net as @rschwieb recommended.

Comment: I edited the text above and thanked you. I think it is an application of Euler's formula to tetrahedron packing.